# Calculated Field Using Group By Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery, calculated-field

I have one table which holds Lessons with theirs attributes such as DepId and FieldId. I have two tables also, about Lesson Departments and Lesson Fields. I need to calculate lesson's weekly times percentage's based on DepId and FieldId. My query as follows:

```
  Select a.FieldName, b.DepName, sum(LessonWeeklyTime), ((sum(LessonWeeklyTime))*100)/(select LessonDep, sum(LessonWeeklyTime) 
    From Lessons 
Group By LessonDep) 
    from Lessons l, Departments b, Fields a 
   Where l.LessonDep=b.DepId 
     And l.LessonField=a.FieldId 
Group By b.DepName,a.FieldName
```

But I am getting error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Appreciate for help.

Comment: Remove `LessonDep` column from `SubQuery` Selected List.

Comment: what is primery key of lesson table

Comment: tried, no use. @ShyamVemula

Comment: LessonId is primary key @kirangadhe

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.  It is the 21st Century, after all.

You should be doing this with window functions:

```
select f.FieldName, d.DepName, sum(LessonWeeklyTime), 
       (sum(LessonWeeklyTime) * 100.0 / 
        sum(sum(LessonWeeklyTime)) over (partition by d.depName)
from Lessons l join
     Departments d
     on l.LessonDep = d.DepId join
     Fields f
     on l.LessonField = f.FieldId 
Group By d.DepName, f.FieldName
```

Comment: Partitioning by LessonDep is not contained in the Group By, so this won't work. Has to be d.DepName instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you may only have one column in your subquery. Try it that way:

```
Select a.FieldName, b.DepName, sum(LessonWeeklyTime), ((sum(LessonWeeklyTime))*100)/(select sum(LessonWeeklyTime) 
    From Lessons 
Group By LessonDep) 
    from Lessons l, Departments b, Fields a 
   Where l.LessonDep=b.DepId 
     And l.LessonField=a.FieldId 
Group By b.DepName,a.FieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
Select a.FieldName, b.DepName, sum(LessonWeeklyTime), ((sum(LessonWeeklyTime))*100)/ sum(c.LessonWeeklyTime)
        from Lessons l, Departments b, Fields a ,(select LessonDep, sum(LessonWeeklyTime) LessonWeeklyTime 
        From Lessons 
Group By LessonDep) c
       Where l.LessonDep=b.DepId 
         And l.LessonField=a.FieldId 
         And l.LessonDep=c.LessonDep
Group By b.DepName,a.FieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the time by necessary codes from 1 table and uses a window function for the percentage. It groups/calculates by the IDs rather than descriptions to improve performance and reduce chance of errors on poor labelling/nulls:

```
WITH CTE AS( SELECT LESSONDEP, LESSONFIELD, SUM(LESSONWEEKLYTIME) AS [TIME] 
FROM [LESSONS] 
GROUP BY LESSONDEP, LESSONFIELD) 
SELECT F.FIELDNAME, D.DEPNAME, L.[TIME], (L.[TIME]*100.0) / (SUM(L.[TIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY L.LESSONDEP) AS [PERCENTAGE] 
FROM CTE L 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON L.LESSONDEP = D.DEPID 
INNER JOIN FIELDS F ON L.LESSONFIELD = F.FIELDID
```